# python- list of tuples loop; check if any tuple element is in the next tuple

Tags: python-3.x, list, tuples

I have a list of tuples like:

`list=[('Jim','Pam'),('Jim','Homer'),('Bart','Marge')]`

I am trying to compare the elements of the current tuple with the elements of the next tuple and print "back to back".

In my list, 'Jim' appears in list element 0 and list element 1, so it should print back to back. This is not the case in list elements 1 and 2.

I've attempted:

```
for pair in list:
    for i in range(len(list)):
        if pair[0] or pair[1] in list[i+1]:
            print("back to back")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can zip `list` with `list[1:]` to get all adjacent pairs.

```
for a, b in zip(lst, lst[1:]):
    if any(x in b for x in a):
        print("back to back")
```